Power analysis for granular and aggregated data
I need to create an A/B test to understand if removing a certain packaging reduces item damages. I have a list of around 2000 items that currently have specific packaging applied, along with their monthly damage rates (the proportion of damaged units vs. on-hand units) for the last six months.
As we're unsure if the experiment is technologically feasible (it will be a scrappy experiment, and we cannot test it on too many items and units), we want to get a ballpark estimate of the number of items and their units needed to achieve significant results.
To do this, I would focus on items with a high enough volume in the network to conduct the experiment quickly. I would identify those with higher damage rates and then determine the appropriate number of items and their sample sizes.
The way I would design this is to first calculate the sample size for items by analyzing the historical data to estimate the variance in damage rates across these top items. This will help us understand how much the damage rates differ from one item to another. I would then perform a power analysis to determine the number of items needed in each group.
To calculate the sample size for units per item, I would estimate the variance in damage rates within individual items. I would define the effect size in terms of the difference in damage rates at the unit level. This could be the same as at the item level or more granular, depending on how consistent the damage rates are within items. Then I would perform a power analysis to calculate the number of units required per item to detect the specified effect.
Is this the right approach for this analysis, and what limitations and considerations do I need to take into account? Do I do power analysis for t-test or proportion tests in this case?
